# How can I make an Ember computed property depend on all descendent properties of a variable?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a computed property that I want to be reevaluated whenever any value in a deeply nested object changes. I understand that `myObj.[]`  can be used to reevaluate computed properties whenever any object in an array changes, but I want this to be recursive.

eg I have

```
// should recalculate whenever myObj.x.y.z changes, or when myObj.a.b.c changes
computed('myObj', function() {
  // ...
})
```

I don't know in advance exactly how the object is structured, and it may be arbitrarily deep.

Neither `computed('myObj.[]', ...)` nor `computed('myObj.@each', ...)` seem to work for this.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: FWIW, I actually wound up flattening the object as best I could and keying off of the flattened object instead, though I had to rely on some a priori knowledge of the structure of the object. Because of that, it's a bit hacky and I'm not totally satisfied w/ it, but I'm sticking with it because it's less convoluted than managing dynamically created computed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember it is possible to define computed properties at runtime

```
import { defineProperty, computed } from '@ember/object';

// define a computed property
defineProperty(myObj, 'nameOfComputed', computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
  return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
}));
```

So taking that a step further, you *could* dynamically create whatever computed property key string you want at runtime (this could be in component's `init()` or something):

```
// define a computed property
let object = {
   foo: 'foo',
   bar: 'bar'
}
this.set('myObj', object);
let keys = Object.keys(object).map((key) => {
  return `myObj.${key}`
});
defineProperty(this, 'someComputed', computed.apply(this, [...keys, function() {
  // do something here
}]));
```

It's up to you to figure out how to properly recursively traverse your objects for all the dependent keys without creating cycles or accessing prototype keys you don't want...or to consider whether or not this is even that good of an idea. Alternatively, you could try to handle the setting of these properties in such a way that retriggers a computation (which would be more in line with DDAU). I can only speculate from what you've provided what works but it's certainly possible to do what you want. See [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7b8cd9122c41bef1b8983ca3a2bc3281?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) in action

Comment: Hmmm... It works, but I'm still sort of holding out hope for a magical solution like a `myObj.@deepEach`, or something. Will accept if I don't find a better answer in the next day or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
could you try anyone computed/obeserver like below..
But try to prefer the computed.

import { observer } from '@ember/object';
import EmberObject, { computed } from '@ember/object';

partOfNameChanged1: observer('myObj','myObj.[]','myObj.@each', function() {
  return 'myObj is changed by obeserver';
})

partOfNameChanged2: computed ('myObj','myObj.[]','myObj.@each', function() {
  return 'myObj is changed by computed';
})

then in your handlebar/template file

{{log 'partOfNameChanged1 is occured' partOfNameChanged1}}
{{log 'partOfNameChanged2 is occured' partOfNameChanged2}}
```

Then you have to associate/assign this `partOfNameChanged1 / partOfNameChanged2` to some where in the handlebar or to any other variable in your .js  file.
As long as you have not assigned this computed/observer property `partOfNameChanged1 /partOfNameChanged2` to somewhere, then you will not get it's value.

Comment: The issue that this doesn't watch grandchildren properties. This works if `myObj.myAttr` changes, but not if `myObj.myAttr.deepAttr` changes.

Comment: can you please change the key above like 
```partOfNameChanged1: computed ('myObj.@each', 'myObj.@each.depAttr' , 'myObj.@each.{depAttr1, depAttr2}' function() {
  return 'myObj is changed by computed';
})
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how deep it goes, let alone what the attributes are. It could be `myObj.myAttr.deepAttr`, and it could be `myObj.myAttr.deepAttr.a.b.c.d.e.f.g`. I don't know what the names of the keys are, nor do I know the structure. New attrs can be arbitrarily created.